# Getting the index of the currently dragged item in Backbone.CollectionView

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

Given a panel

```
var panel = new Backbone.CollectionView({...})
```

How do I get the current model being sorted?

```
panel.on('sortStart', function(e) {
    var index = something;
});
```

Comment: you want to get the complete collection sorted ,if not what do you mean by getting model sorted?

Comment: If i understands you correctly, you should trigger that event from your model view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you use some kind of UI manipulation tool for example jQuery UI. As Lesha said in her [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26071969/getting-the-index-of-the-currently-dragged-item-in-backbone-collectionview#comment40850778_26071969) it can be done through triggering of event on the model view.

```
//creting children view
var PanelItem = Backbone.View.extend({

  events: {
    "sortStart": "sortEventPropagation"
  },

  initialize : function (options) {
    this.parentView = options.parentView;
  },

  sortEventPropagation: function(){
    this.parentView.trigger('sort:start:propagated', this.model);
  },  
})
```

Everytime you are creating panelItem view you need to pass it panel in options as parentView.

```
var childView = new PanelItem({
  parentView: panel
})
```

And on panel you could easily listenTo `sort:start:propagated` event

```
var Panel = Backbone.CollectionView.extend({
  initialize: function(){
    this.listenTo(this, 'sort:start:propagated', function(model){
      //Do magic with model
    })
  },
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I already got this working. I had to bind to both sortstop (on the ul element for dragging between lists) and sortStop (on the Backbone.CollectionView).